# Is the System namespace implicit in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I've been playing with *PowerShell* lately, and I recently found out that the `System.` namespace does not seem to be mandatory.  For instance:

```
[System.Math]::PI
[Math]::PI
```

Or:

```
New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

Are equivalent.  However, when loading assemblies the story is different:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Windows.Forms  # This fails
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

I'm guessing this is a *.NET* thing, but I fail to find clear explicit documentation about it.

Can the `System.` namespace be ommitted safely then?  (Except for the assembly loading, that is)  Are there any other cases where it's mandatory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `System` namespace can be omitted. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators) (italics mine):

> The .NET type can be written as a type name in brackets or a string, such as `[DateTime]` or `"DateTime"` for **System.DateTime**. If the type is not at the root of the system namespace, specify the full name of the object type. *You can omit "System.".* For example, to specify **System.Diagnostics.Process**, enter `[System.Diagnostics.Process]`, `[Diagnostics.Process]`, or `"Diagnostics.Process"`.